# On progress Not working in Ajax Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, xmlhttprequest

I have a website that when a user submits the data a function runs and requests a php backend to insert the data into the database but i want to display the spinner on the button when the request has been sent but the on progress function just not working .i have tried everything else please help me.

here is my code of JavaScript

```
let s_form = document.querySelector("#con-form");

s_form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
let name = document.getElementById("name").value;
let email = document.getElementById("email").value;
let mobno = document.getElementById("mobno").value;
let concern = document.getElementById("concern").value;
const xhr_obj = {
name: name,
email: email,
mobno: mobno,
concern: concern,
};
let data_send = JSON.stringify(xhr_obj);
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost/dc/utilities/php/h_f_s.php", true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
xhr.onprogress = function () {
console.log("appendChild");
 //this is not working why can you find out
};
xhr.onload = function () {
console.log("loaded");
 //this works perfect
};
xhr.send(data_send);
});
```

Comment: `onprogress` is used to indicate how many bytes have been sent to the server, such as when uploading a file.  For the request shown, it seems likely that the entire request is successfully sent to the server immediately so there's no additional progress to show.  Can you indicate exactly what "progress" you're expecting to see?

Comment: Until the server responded to the request and give the result i want to show a spinner. Can you suggest some function to do it please.

Comment: Sure... Show a spinner, make the AJAX request, remove the spinner when the request completes (in `onload` and or potentially `onerror`).  You're not looking for "progress".  You're just looking for when the AJAX request completes.